# Cómo coger un valor de una variable de otra función

Tags: django, python-3.7

pues tengo esta función tan gigante (donde la variable que me interesa se encuentra al final de la función y la variable no está en un "return"):

```
def genera_nodo(self, datos: dict) -> List[RTEjecBasedNodoWrapper]:
    rr_qs = datos['rr_qs']
    lei_ejecutor = datos['lei_ejecutor']
    remitente = datos['remitente']
    pata_dict = dict()
    pata_qs = PataRentaPercapita.objects.filter(datos_comunes__in=rr_qs).select_related(
        'datos_comunes',
        'datos_comunes__segur',
        'broker_titular',
        'codigo_corto',
        'entidad__titular__inversion',
        'entidad__titular__juridico',
        'entidad__titular__individual',
        'entidad__titular__inversion__gestor',
        'entidad__titular__juridico__gestor',
        'entidad__titular__juridico__rentabilidad'
    )
    for le in pata_qs:
        pata_dict[le.datos_comunes_id] = le

    nodo_ejec_qs = CapitalEjecutad.objects.non_polymorphic().distinct().filter(asign__agrup_id__in=list(pata_dict.keys()))
    finder = RTEjecNodoFinder(list(nodo_ejec_qs.values_list('pk', flat=True)), remitente, lei_ejecutor)

    ejec_qs = CapitalAsign.objects.non_polymorphic().filter(agrup__in=pata_dict.keys()).select_related(
        'ejecucion',
        'ejecucion__segur',
        'ejecucion__sede',
        'ejecucion__order',
    reutilizar_cancels: Set[Transaccion] = set()
    all_nodos: List[RTEjecBasedNodoWrapper] = []

    for ejec, asign_iter in groupby(ejec_qs, lambda a: a.ejecucion):
        nodo_gen = self.NodeCreator(self._data_cache, remitente, lei_ejecutor, pata_dict, ejec)
        for a in asign_iter:
            nodo_gen.add_asign(a)
        try:
            for rt_nodo in nodo_gen.rt_nodos():
                instancia_existente = finder.find_already_sent(rt_nodo)

                    rr = pata_dict[next(iter(nodo_gen.titular_asign.values()))[0].agrup_id].datos_comunes
                    asign_qs = rr.asignacion_set.non_polymorphic()
                    asign_qs = asign_qs.exclude(size=0)
                    if asign_qs.exists():
                        for asignacion in asign_qs.select_related('ejecucion', 'ejecucion__order'):
                            rr_asignacion = Extractor.genero_id(rr, asignacion, asignacion.ejecucion)
                            print(rr_asignacion) # Este valor es el que me interesa coger
        except ...
    return all_nodos
```

Y quiero coger el valor de la variable 'rr_asignacion', para crear una columna en el fichero admin.py
La otra forma que se me ocurre de hacer lo sería con un filter o un get, pero como no tengo una FK  entre otras cosas lo descarto por el momento.

```
admin.py        
from infocomercial.rt.extractors.base import Extractor

def valor_asignacion(self):
    if Extractor.genera_nodo(datos, rr_asignacion): #No sé si sería algo así
        return # rr_asignacion
    else:
        return '-'
```

¿Cómo podría usar esa variable?
o ¿qué otra forma habría para hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes añadirla al return:

```
def genera_nodo(self, datos: dict) -> List[RTEjecBasedNodoWrapper]:
    ....
    ....
    ....
    return all_nodos, rr_asignacion
```

y luego llamas a la función obteniendo los dos valores:

```
all_nodos, rr_asignacion = Extractor.genera_nodo(datos)
```

Otra opción, si no quieres obtener "all_nodos" sería añadirle un parámetro a la función genera_nodo y que devuelva una cosa u otra en función de ese parámetro:

```
def genera_nodo(self, datos: dict, only_rr=False) -> List[RTEjecBasedNodoWrapper]:
    ....
    ....
    ....
    if only_rr:
        return rr_asignacion
    else:
        return all_nodos
```

y luego llamas a la función así:

```
rr_asignacion = Extractor.genera_nodo(datos, only_rr=True)
```